# Makefile error 1

Tags: c, makefile

I keep getting the error:
make: *** [first] Error 1

I used this to make my makefile.

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS  = -Wall -ansi -pedantic
all: first

first: first.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o first       
first.o:
first.o: first.c first.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c first.c 
clean:
    rm -f first first.o
```

It's a generic form that is suppose to work for our assignments. However, I can not get it to execute.

I don't know if

```
gcc: no input files
```

Is part of the issue.

Comment: Please edit to fix the indentation in your Makefile.

Comment: This is an assignment and you are learning old ANSI-C? Huh! Change school.

Comment: Pot the whole error message, This is just one line and only tells make has encountered an error. Post a [mcve]

Comment: That was the only error listed. Gcc: no input files filled by make:*** [first] error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o first
```

This will expand to something like `gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o first`.  Note that there are no input files specified, just as the error message says.  You need to add `first.o` at the end.

Comment: I fixed it and the error is gone. But first and first.o is not being removed.

Comment: @JavvaTheHutt: What do you mean?

Comment: I thought the directory is only suppose to have three files left at the end. First.h , first.c and makefile. First.o and first are still listed in the directory. Isn't that what the clean line is suppose to do? Remove them so they don't show up when command ls is used later.

Comment: Did you run "make clean"?

Comment: thanks! Tbh I'm not sure how makefiles work. Thank again